# Tornadofx onFocus listener

Tags: javafx, view, kotlin, listener, tornadofx

Is there something like an `onFocus()` method, which I could override like the `onDock()` and `onCreate()` in the view class?

In the documentation there is only written about [live reloading](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/wiki/Components#live-reloading) of views.

I tried combining that with, the `onDock()` and `onCreate()` method, but, even though it "works", it's not a very neat way of replicating `onFocus` behaviour.

Is there a simple way to have a "listener" method that's called when the view/fragment comes to front/on focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The View is a container, and not an UI element in the sense of the JavaFX context, so it cannot receive an `onFocus` callback. However, you can register one with the current window or even the root node of the View. If you're opening a window, you could register such an even with the `currentWindow` property. If you're not opening a window, you could register it with the `root` property of the View. Here is an example listening for a single focus change event from the `currentWindow`:

```
override fun onDock() {
    currentStage?.focusedProperty()?.onChangeOnce {

    }
}
```